# Programmatically access Devise LDAP config in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ldap

I'm using Devise with LDAP authentication in a Rails 4 application.  The `ldap.yml` looks like

```
development:
  host: my.ldap.server
  port: 636
  attribute: sAMAccountName
  base: OU=Accounts,DC=my,DC=ldap,DC=server
  admin_user: CN=ServiceAccount,OU=LDAP,OU=Service Accounts,DC=my,DC=ldap,DC=server
  admin_password: super_secret_password
  ssl: true

production:
  ...
```

I want to be able to access this programmatically, but I cannot figure out how to do it.  I can access by reading directly from the file by doing

> [ldap_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(::Devise.ldap_config || "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml")).result)[Rails.env]](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/master/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/ldap/connection.rb#L10)

However, this is not 100% accurate because if the values in the file had changed without the Rails server being restarted, the "live" values that Rails is actually using would be different.

How can I get to these "live" values?  I can't find anything on this.

Comment: Does ``Devise.ldap_config`` work on your console? And ``User.ldap_config``? Also, I don't see a big problem accessing the `yaml` file directly: if you change that values, you'll need to restart the server in any case!

Comment: @dgilperez:  `Devise.ldap_config` gives nil and `User.ldap_config` does not exist.  Yeah, it's not that big of a deal, but something about it bugs me.

Comment: What about `Devise::LDAP::Connection.new.ldap`? That should let you access `Devise::LDAP::Connection.new.ldap.host`, `Devise::LDAP::Connection.new.ldap.port` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the configuration using this:

```
> Devise::LDAP::Connection.new.ldap
=> #<Net::LDAP:0x0000010e9d2da8
 @auth={:method=>:anonymous},
 @base="OU=Accounts,DC=my,DC=ldap,DC=server",
 @encryption={:method=>:simple_tls},
 @force_no_page=false,
 @host="my.ldap.server",
 @open_connection=nil,
 @port=636,
 @verbose=false>

> Devise::LDAP::Connection.new.ldap.host
=> "my.ldap.server"
> Devise::LDAP::Connection.new.ldap.port
=> 636
...
>
```

Like I said, I don't see much trouble in reading the file directly like you wrote. If you change the `ldap.yml`, you'll need to restart the server to see the changes in your LDAP configuration anyway! If you prefer, you can set up an initializer like this:

```
# config/initializers/ldap.rb
LDAP_CONFIG = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml")).result)[Rails.env].with_indifferent_access
```

And then in your code:

```
LDAP_CONFIG[:admin_user] #=> "CN=ServiceAccount,OU=LDAP,OU=Service Accounts,DC=my,DC=ldap,DC=server"
LDAP_CONFIG[:admin_password] #=> "super_secret_password"
LDAP_CONFIG[:host] #=> "my.ldap.server"
```

Comment: This work for most of the properties.  It is not straightforward for `admin_user` or `admin_password`.  `Devise::LDAP::Connection.new.ldap` is of type `Net::LDAP` (as you can see in the output), and browsing the source of [Net::LDAP](https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap/blob/master/lib/net/ldap.rb) reveals that it stores the name/password in `@auth` (also as seen above).  But since `@auth` is not public, the only way to get to it is with some cleverness (a la [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2132392/209107) for example).

Comment: I see. Too hacky. I'd just use this method for the visible things, and revert to the file for the auth settings. Or just go for a initializer + constant like in my update.